# Why do I lose JavaScript intellisense after running my project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, javascript-intellisense

For some reason I lose JavaScript intellisense after debugging my ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio 2012.

You can see that when I start, I have full intellisense. In the below picture I get knockoutjs intellisense:

[image: intellisense works]

However, as soon as I debug the application I lose intellisense. For example, if I hit F5 to debug [update: incidentally, this also occurs with CNTL-F5] when I return to my code I lose intellisense:

[image: intellisense doesn't work]

The only way I've found to get intellisense to work again is to go **Tools** -> **Import and Export Settings** -> **Reset all settings**. The problem is that this only continues to work until I run the application again.

Does anyone know how to permanently fix this issue? Thanks!

**UPDATE**: It appears this is related to ReSharper (I'm using 7.0.1). If I change it from **ReSharper** to **Visual Studio** intellisense under the General Options for ReSharper the problem goes away. I guess this changes my question slightly - how do I get intellisense to work for frameworks like knockoutjs when using ReSharper?

Comment: I experience this behavior with ASP.NET empty, web forms, and mvc applications.

Comment: I am not sure of the others, but in mvc there is a workaround:
`@if(false){
 <script src="" />
}`
will allow intellisense to work.

Comment: Perhaps it will help with MVC, but in my current simple repro I'm using an empty web application project with the JS files and an HTML page - it's about as simple as it gets. I assume that if I can solve this case it will solve the others.

Comment: @TravisJ It appears that this issue is related to ReSharper. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I lost intellisense also other than .cs files recently. I started to disable VS extensions one by one until it get fixed. So I discovered that after I remove one of the VS Extensions (which was related about TFS) Re-sharper started to work again with full power of intellisense.

So if none of your suggestions are not working, I would suggest you to disable extensions and check if ReSharper works again so you can re-enable them until ReSharper breaks then you can discover which extension is evil for your ReSharper. Good luck.